# Accessing Apple SDK Documentation

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to write a command line script to access Apple SDK docsets (like perldoc for perl or ri for ruby). Apple has a tool called **docsetutil** which will let you search a docset, but it is very limited (for example, you can't do a partial search). Is there a more powerful way to access the docs without having to manually parse the HTML documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can do a partial search with it! Just make sure you quote your query!

```
DOCSET="/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiPhone3_0.iPhoneLibrary.docset"
docsetutil search -skip-text -query "UITabl*" $DOCSET
```